# Windows 10 ~ Blackscreen on Login ~ Cannot Access ExplorerFrame.dll

Tags: windows-10, black-screen-of-death

Occasionally, when I log in to Windows, I get a blackscreen. I then have to use [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Del] to bring up the cut-screen and log out and log in again to get Windows to work properly.

In the Event Viewer, the following four errors are logged in that order whenever this happens:

```
Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, version: 10.0.19041.964, time stamp: 0x8aeeaedf
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.964, time stamp: 0x812662a7
Exception code: 0xc0000006
Fault offset: 0x00000000000491fb
Faulting process ID: 0x1b68
Faulting application start time: 0x01d750a2f1e2bf97
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report ID: d7dea398-0d32-47ef-a198-61a9bf38cdb3
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

```
Windows cannot access the file C:\Windows\System32\ExplorerFrame.dll for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program Windows Explorer because of this error.

Program: Windows Explorer
File: C:\Windows\System32\ExplorerFrame.dll

The error value is listed in the Additional Data section.
User Action
1. Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again.
2. If the file still cannot be accessed and
    - It is on the network, your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem with the network and that the server can be contacted.
    - It is on a removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the disk is fully inserted into the computer.
3. Check and repair the file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run, type CMD, and then click OK. At the command prompt, type CHKDSK /F, and then press ENTER.
4. If the problem persists, restore the file from a backup copy.
5. Determine whether other files on the same disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard disk, contact your administrator or computer hardware vendor for further assistance.

Additional Data
Error value: C0000010
Disk type: 3
```

```
Faulting application name: SearchIndexer.exe, version: 7.0.19041.844, time stamp: 0x688628e1
Faulting module name: MSSRCH.DLL, version: 7.0.19041.844, time stamp: 0xe4de8936
Exception code: 0xc0000006
Fault offset: 0x00000000000671b8
Faulting process ID: 0x1b78
Faulting application start time: 0x01d750a2f1e4ff6f
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\SearchIndexer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\MSSRCH.DLL
Report ID: 603a95f0-6d61-4e55-bc12-7de2b7a1e7ed
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

```
Windows cannot access the file C:\Windows\System32\mssrch.dll for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program Microsoft Windows Search Indexer because of this error.

Program: Microsoft Windows Search Indexer
File: C:\Windows\System32\mssrch.dll

The error value is listed in the Additional Data section.
User Action
1. Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again.
2. If the file still cannot be accessed and
    - It is on the network, your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem with the network and that the server can be contacted.
    - It is on a removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the disk is fully inserted into the computer.
3. Check and repair the file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run, type CMD, and then click OK. At the command prompt, type CHKDSK /F, and then press ENTER.
4. If the problem persists, restore the file from a backup copy.
5. Determine whether other files on the same disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard disk, contact your administrator or computer hardware vendor for further assistance.

Additional Data
Error value: C0000010
Disk type: 3
```

It obviously can't be that the drive can't be found, since C is where Windows 10 is installed, and if the drive was not accessible, it wouldn't be able to start Windows 10 in the first place.

Does anyone have any ideas why this happens, and what I can do against this?

Comment: I would use the appropriate SFC and DISM commands to repair your Windows installation

Comment: What have you done to your setup, to cause such errors? If you have System Restore enabled, rollback to before this was done.

Comment: What exactly is the "cut-screen"?